# PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8412174 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknow

Tags: php, heroku, slim

I'm working on an heroku app thah will run PHP and slim framework to create an REST API service. I have an endpoint that is responsable to accept uploaded files using `FormData()` on the front-end and that after processing will give the result back to the user so the content can be downloaded. I'm having some trouble with slim and heroku. If I try to upload a png image I will get this error from slim:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException:  is not a valid uploaded file in /app/vendor/slim/psr7/src/UploadedFile.php:165
```

I don't know why this occur, it seems that the file isn't passed to the script, I'm supposing this because there is no file name into the error message, I'm using a [library](https://github.com/siriusphp/upload) to manage the upload process, the library will accept the `Psr7 UploadedFileInterface` that is provided by slim when a file is uploaded and works fine in my localhost server, the problem is probably only with slim and I don't know how to fix it.

Another problem is with my heroku dyno settings. I've created a `.user.ini` file inside the root of the deployed project but I get the error about the `POST` content length. This is the content of the file:

```
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
memory_limit = 256M
```

Is there a way to fix this two problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to the problem. I forget to commit the modifications I've made when the `.user.ini` file was created. I've just prepared all files for commit and then using the terminal I've pushed the updated files to my heroku app.

```
git commit -am "commit message"
git push heroku master
```